# Attempted to call function "yaml_parse_file" from the global namespace

Tags: php, symfony, cron, symfony4

I am new to Symfony, Facing problem while trying to run the cron job. I am really clueless, whats wrong here. It seems that I am trying to access some functions present in `app/config/functions.php` from the global namespace, But I can't figure out which namespace is it. Following is my code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use App\Services\Upcontent\Upcontent;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class UpcontentRefreshCommand extends Command
{
protected static $defaultName = 'app:upcontent-refresh';
private $upcontent;

public function __construct(Upcontent $upcontent)
{
    $this->upcontent = $upcontent;

    parent::__construct();
}

protected function configure()
{

}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $output->writeln([
        '',
        '=================',
        'Upcontent Refresh',
        '=================',
        '',
    ]);

    $output->writeln('Clearing Cache...');
    clear_cache();
    $output->writeln('Cache Cleared');

    $output->writeln('Refreshing Sports Topic...');
    $output->writeln('Loading, be patient...');
    $sports = $this->upcontent->getTopic('########');

    $output->writeln([
        '',
        '=====================',
        'End Upcontent Refresh',
        '=====================',
        '',
    ]);
}
}

?>
```

The error occur when I run, `php72 bin/console app:upcontent-refresh` Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to update the "autoload"-section to make sure that your custom functions.php is loaded.

```js
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4" {
            "App\\": "src/"
        },
        "files": ["app/config/functions.php"]
    }
}
```

You might also want to refactor that file to instead move the functions into some kind of service-class, e.g. like this:

```php
# src/Yaml/Parser.php
<?php

namespace App\Yaml;

class Parser
{
    public function parseFile(string $fileName)
    {
        // The logic from your yaml_parse_file() inside your functions.php
    }
}
```

Then in your command (or wherever you need your custom yaml parsing) inject the service:

```php
use App\Yaml\Parser;

class MyService
{
    private $yamlParser;

    public function __construct(Parser $yamlParser)
    {
        $this->yamlParser = $yamlParser;
    }

    // ...
    public function something()
    {
        $this->yamlParser->parseFile($filename);
    }
}
```

Since Symfony provides a Yaml-component, you might even want to use that instead.